# Program lags due to too many views

Tags: android, performance, view, android-imageview, android-drawable

I wrote an android app, that creates multiple simple views (`ImageViews showing a drawable`). After each touch new views get added. While it works fine with a few views, it goes up too 10000 views in the end (on purpose). This makes the app really laggy.

Actually there is not that much happening, most of the views just stay the same during the whole run of the app. Just a few get updated each time a touch happens.

I don't know that much about android programming yet. Do you have any ideas, how I could implement this more efficient? Currently I'm just adding views to a `RelativeLayout`.

### Edit

Here is an example of how it should look like:
[image]

Clicking a big circle makes it into small circles. If nothing touches the circle, it won't change. I create a smaller circle once the bigger one was destroyed, so there is no overlapping of views.

Comment: Depends on how those views are laid out. Are they all visible at once? Are they listed? How much of the `View` functionality do you need? I think 10k views is way too much - you probably want to directly draw to `Canvas`.

Comment: It is hard to tell, because I don't know if you stack them, or show them beneath each other. A screenshot would make it more clear. If you stack them you could destroy views that are not visible anymore, because other views on top. If they are shown beneath each other a recyclerview is probably the best solution as Sergey Shustikov suggests.

Answer (score 1):

The best way - use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=en) for this.

#### From docs :

> This widget is a container **for displaying large data** sets that can be scrolled very efficiently by maintaining a limited number of views. Use the RecyclerView widget when you have data collections whose elements change at runtime based on user action or network events.

[RecyclerView.LayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html) will be also a friend to you with relationship with RecyclerView. It will helpfull to you. You will can lay out your views as you need:

[image]

## Update

If you want layout views as you pointed :

[image]

For the better performance you should abandon from `RelativeLayout` and `ImageView` concept.

*For my point of view, the best way to do that - write a custom view.*

### Draw circles on Canvas - why not?

Comment: I animate the views, that is the reason I don't want to draw on a canvas. This is better achievable for views. Is there no way to prevent the system from updating all views?

Comment: @Jonas how you animate your Views?

Comment: With an `ObjectAnimator`, animating the scale of the circles.

Comment: any update on this project? it sounds as interesting as it seems complex...